# Install LIBCURL-DEVEL on SUSE 12.4 to use CURL R package

Tags: r, linux, curl, libcurl, suse

I'm working with a SUSE SLE 12.4

```
> cat /etc/SuSE-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12
PATCHLEVEL = 4
```

I'm trying to install the library `curl` for R [3.6], but I get this error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
```

`libcurl4` (version  7.60.0-2.11) is installed.
As suggested from the error message I tried to install the Linux Package `libcurl-devel`.
Unsurprisingly, since I'm dealing with a dev package, I get this message:

```
> sudo zypper install libcurl-devel
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'libcurl-devel' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'libcurl-devel' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

I tried to find an online repo that could provide for that package. I found nothing.

Can anyone help me?
If you need more infos, I'll be happy to provide them.

As requested, here you have more infos.

```
>  zypper se *curl*
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name            | Summary                                | Type
--+-----------------+----------------------------------------+-----------
i | curl            | A Tool for Transferring Data from URLs | package
  | curl            | A Tool for Transferring Data from URLs | srcpackage
i | libcurl4        | Version 4 of cURL shared library       | package
i | libcurl4-32bit  | Version 4 of cURL shared library       | package
  | perl-WWW-Curl   | Perl extension interface for libcurl   | package
  | perl-WWW-Curl   | Perl extension interface for libcurl   | srcpackage
i | python-pycurl   | PycURL -- cURL library module          | package
  | python-pycurl   | PycURL -- cURL library module          | srcpackage
  | python3-pycurl  | PycURL -- cURL library module          | package
  | python3-pycurl  | PycURL -- cURL library module          | srcpackage
  | qemu-block-curl | cURL block support for QEMU            | package
```

```
> zypper se libcurl*
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name           | Summary                          | Type
--+----------------+----------------------------------+--------
i | libcurl4       | Version 4 of cURL shared library | package
i | libcurl4-32bit | Version 4 of cURL shared library | package
```

Comment: can you provide output for `zypper se *curl*` and `zypper se libcurl*` ?

Comment: also If you have installation media. you can search in that as well. High probability of it being there. may not be updated version.

Comment: @Devidas I edited my question. I do have an installation media and it's connected, but it doesn't find it there.

Comment: can you check whether installation media is part of repos `zypper lr -u` ? if not add it to repo and rerun zypper se.

Comment: Yes it is. It's Enabled. And I'm sure it works because I installed other packages this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go here [here](https://scc.suse.com/packages), search for `libcurl-devel` for your SUSE version, download it and install it locally using provided instructions. I do see that `libcurl-devel` is available for your system.

**UPDATE**
In my understanding, the problem is that you don't have the SDK module activated in your system. If you don't have administrative privileges, ask the administrator to activate the SDK module by running:

`SUSEConnect -p sle-sdk/12.4/x86_64`

After this module is activated, run:

`sudo zypper install libcurl-devel`

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion looks promising and it looks to be the right answer. Unfortunately, I can't test it right now. For reasons unknown to me (because I am not the one who set up the machine), the SO is not registered. And it is required to be registered to download the package. I'm waiting for an answer from the person who did the job. I'll get back to you before the bounty ends. In the meantime, if you're aware of any workarounds, it would be perfect.

Comment: @Edo In my understanding, the problem is that you don't have the SDK module activated in your system. This is why the system can't find the `libcurl-devel` package only available in the SDK (`SUSE Linux Enterprise Software Development Kit 12 SP4 x86_64`). See my updated answer

Comment: I believe you're absolutely right. When I run that command I get this output
`Please register your system using the --regcode parameter, or provide the --url parameter to register against SMT.`

Comment: @Edo I wish I could help more, but at this point it is only your administrator that can help you proceed with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your package database prior to installing:

```
sudo zypper ref
```